# How to use CONCAT and IFNULL inside DB::raw simultaneously in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to use ifnull and concat in same DB::raw, but i don't get idea about that.
Here i want to get is, if member_name is null then return N/A. My query is like this:

```
DB::raw('(select concat(users.fname, "", " ", users.lname,"") as fullname from users where id = 1) as member_name')
```

Comment: Does Laravel play any role in the question? I mean, do you have a working SQL query that does not work when feeded to `DB::raw()`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i want to use this in laravel eloquent query. The query i have posted works fine but I also want to check ifnull in same quey. I mean, concat fname and lname of members and return N/A if name is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try with this simple way. it's works

```
 DB::raw("SELECT 
    IF((users.fname AND users.lname) IS NULL,
        'N/A',
        CONCAT(users.fname,
                ' ',
                IFNULL(users.lname, ''))) AS member_name
FROM
    users
WHERE
    id = 1

");
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this help you,

```
$user = \DB::table('users')
           ->where('id', 1)
           ->select(\DB::raw('CONCAT(fname, \' \', lname) as member_name'))
           ->first();
```